# "Products contains invalid products" Nativescript Xcode Archive

Tags: xcode, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have succeeded to build an Archive in Xcode 10.1 but cannot pass the signature analyze.

Everytime I have the following error:

```
/Users/lambda/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-11-19/My App 19-11-18 21.50.xcarchive/Products contains invalid products.

Multiple binaries share the same codesign path:
/Applications/My App.app/app/tns_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/Current

Binaries:
/Applications/My App.app/app/tns_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
/Applications/My App.app/app/tns_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Electron Framework

This can happen if your build process copies frameworks by following symlinks.
```

I can't find anywhere how to solve this.

The certificate was regenerated and produce no errors.
I have also checked those paths inside the build and seen no symlinks.

I use Nativescript Vue 2.0.2.

Comment: May I ask why you have electron package within your app, that shouldn't be there right?

Comment: @Manoj Honestly, I don't know. I assume that it should be there. A dependency of a dependency I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron is for desktop app development, I don't think it should be there in your dependencies.

Comment: I manually deleted all trace of Electron and it passed the validation! Thank you for your help! ;-)

Comment: It seems that "tns_modules" was installed (by me) in a previous manipulation... removing this dependency seems to fix this case. :-)

Comment: I had this issue using Nativescript with Vue, because I had added '@vue/devtools' as a dependency, rather than devDependency. Moving it in package.json, deleting the 'platforms' folder, and re-running the build fixed it.